# How to prove $T-\Delta$ and $K-\Delta$ are homotopy eqiuvallence

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\Delta $ be a triangle, and $T=S^1 \times S^1$ ,$K$ is a Klein bottle.How to prove $T-\Delta$ and $K-\Delta$ are homotopy eqiuvallence

Comment: Hint : they both retract on the wedge of two circles.

Comment: couly you show me more details?Thanks!

Comment: Do you know their polygon representation? You can see what Nicolas said  more easily there.

Comment: I have no idea what their polygon representation are,sorry for that

Comment: You need to know that $T$ is a quotient of a square by appropriate gluing and similarly for $K$. Then it is very easy to visualize the retraction.

Comment: How to prove it in details not in visualization？

Comment: Bruce : sorry I didn't see your message (you can do "@NicolasHemelsoet" e.g if you want someone to be notified). Not in visualization, prove that a square minus a triangle retracts on its boundary, this is easy. And then it finishes the proof.